# How to get DAG files from a git master repository (latest tag) to bitnami helm

Tags: gitlab, bitnami

I'm using a project on GITLab to store my DAGs and using BitNami's HELM to synchronize Kubernates with the GIT repository. This works perfectly, however I have to inform a branch. It turns out that in production we work with TAGs and I would like the synchronization between Helm and GitLab to be done by the last tag.
Could you help me on this issue?

How should Helm's configuration be done so that it synchronizes with the last existing tag for a branch (master)?

Comment: I don't think this is supported at the moment. You would need to automatically detect the latest tag using `git describe` or something like that at the moment the git init container is created. However what the container does at the moment is to clone the branch you specify. See: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/49adc63b672da976c55af2e077aa5648a357b77f/bitnami/airflow/templates/_git_helpers.tpl#L88

You could open an issue/PR asking for or implenting this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, after a few attempts, I found that it is possible to use `git.sync.command` and include the `git checkout $ (git describe --tags)`